# LibGDX, best way to store multiple different sprite positions

Tags: libgdx

So I am currently creating a small game that contains 25 total sprites in one Scene. 1 sprite is the player and the rest are enemy sprites.

What I am trying to do is set the position of the 24 enemy sprites to their own unique areas. This can be easily done by simply doing `sprite.setPosition(x,y)` but this would mean I would have to write 24 different `setPosition` statements.

My sprites are all stored in an `ArrayList` which adds the 24 sprites to the list which are then rendered 24 times in the `render()` method. Currently all 24 sprites are rendered at 0,0.

Is there a simpler and more efficient way to set each sprites position which can then be updated to work with deltatime to move the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You could store each of the sprites in an array, then simply set the positions of all of them to be on some random position on the radius of an expanding circle as you iterate over all the enemy sprites:

```
...
private Sprite[] enemies;
...
public void positionSprites() {
    for(int i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        //Gets the enemy from the array.
        Sprite enemy = enemies[i];
        //Generates a random angle between 0 and 2pi in radians to move the sprite to.
        double randAngle = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
        //Calculates the radius of the circle to be the (iteration count + 1) * the diagonal size of the sprites to prevent them from overlapping.
        double radius = (i + 1) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(enemy.getWidth(), 2) + Math.pow(enemy.getHeight(), 2));
        //Calculates the position the enemy at the random angle along the circle.
        float x = (float) radius * Math.cos(angle), y = (float) radius * Math.sin(angle);
        //Sets the enemy position to the new position.
        enemy.setPosition(x, y);
    }
}
```